# Registering and login users in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: authentication, azure, windows-phone-8, authorization, azure-mobile-services

I was following [this series about Mobile Services](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Exploring_custom_identity_in_Mobile_Services_Day_12_.aspx) and I am using examples in latest tutorial. Now I want to impelement registering and login in Windows Phone for example. I changed to Insert permission to anyone with application key and I can Insert new user by this code:

```
await accountTable.InsertAsync(new accounts() { Username = "admin", Password = "mypassword" });
```

But I don't know how can I now check for login user? How to get token?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-dotnet/

Comment: I saw it before. It's using LoginAsync but it needs MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider as parameter but I don't know where get it for custom authentication.

Comment: Please please please do not store passwords on your database. Do what other sites do and store only a (salted) hash of it.

Comment: Ofcourse it's salted hash in database. It's using javascript code in tutorial which I mentioned in question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - the "insert" operation with a username/password threw me off. I should have looked at the tutorial first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post you referred was written at the end of last year, when there was no support for custom APIs on Azure Mobile Services - the only place where you could have scripts executed for user calls were on tables. Nowadays you should actually use custom APIs for that - where you can define two APIs - one for registering the user, and another one for login. On the client, when you call login, the API would validate the user name / password, then return the Zumo token (created with the script shown in that blog post), which the client can then set to the `CurrentUser` property of the `MobileServiceClient` object.

Something like the code below:

```
var loginInput = new JObject();
loginInput.Add("userName", "theUserName");
loginInput.Add("password", "thePassword");
var loginResult = await client.InvokeApiAsync("login", loginInput);
client.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser((string)loginResult["user"]);
client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = (string)loginResult["token"];
```

And the API would look something like the code below:

```
exports.post = function(req, res) {
    var user = req.body.userName;
    var pass = req.body.password;
    validateUserNamePassword(user, pass, function(error, userId, token) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(401, { error: "Unauthorized" });
        } else {
            res.send(200, { user: userId, token: token });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks exactly advice what I was looking for :)

Comment: very frustating to work with custom authentication in azure mobile services. No idea why the mess it up like this. Parse.com authentication is just so awesome.