# Custom Authentication Azure Mobile Services by Api

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am creating a custom authentication via API on Azure Mobile Service, and picked based on this answer:

[Registering and login users in Azure Mobile Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893218/registering-and-login-users-in-azure-mobile-services)

Then joined with the code of the previous link to create the authentication token.

But I get "internal server error" when I invoke the API. The error happens in here: "...results.length..."

```
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    var iterations = 1000;
    var bytes = 32;
    var aud = "Custom";
    var masterKey = "wkeHEoWUaPJSHsSOcWgmVLOZbIpeeg92";
    var _request;
    var _response;

    exports.post = function(request, response) {
        var user = request.body.userName;
        var pass = request.body.password;
        _request = request;
        _response = response
        validateUserNamePassword(user, pass, function(error, userId, token) {
            if (error) {
                response.send(401, { error: "Unauthorized" });
            } else {
                response.send(200, { user: userId, token: token });
            }
        });
    }

    function validateUserNamePassword(user, pass, funcao){

        var accounts = _request.service.tables.getTable('account');

        accounts
            .where({ userid : user })
            .read({
                success: function(results) 
                {
                    if (results.length === 0) 
                    {
                        _response.send(401, { error: "Unauthorized1" });
                        console.log("Incorrect username or password");
                        _request.respond(401, "Incorrect username or password");
                    }
                    else 

                        _response.send(401, { error: "Unauthorized2" });
                        var account = results[0];
                        hash(item.password, account.salt, function(err, h) {
                            var incoming = h;
                            if (slowEquals(incoming, account.password)) {
                                var expiry = new Date().setUTCDate(new Date().getUTCDate() + 30);
                                var userId = aud + ":" + account.id;
                                _request.respond(200, {
                                    userId: userId,
                                    token: zumoJwt(expiry, aud, userId, masterKey) 
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                _request.respond(401, "Incorrect username or password");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
    }



    function hash(text, salt, callback) {
        crypto.pbkdf2(text, salt, iterations, bytes, function(err, derivedKey){
            if (err) { callback(err); }
            else {
                var h = new Buffer(derivedKey).toString('base64');
                callback(null, h);
            }
        });
    }

    function slowEquals(a, b) {
        var diff = a.length ^ b.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++) {
            diff |= (a[i] ^ b[i]);
        }
        return diff === 0;
    }

    function zumoJwt(expiryDate, aud, userId, masterKey) {

        var crypto = require('crypto');

        function base64(input) {
            return new Buffer(input, 'utf8').toString('base64');
        }

        function urlFriendly(b64) {
            return b64.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(new RegExp("=", "g"), '');
        }

        function signature(input) {
            var key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(masterKey + "JWTSig").digest('binary');
            var str = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(input).digest('base64');
            return urlFriendly(str);
        }

        var s1 = '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT","kid":0}';
        var j2 = {
            "exp":expiryDate.valueOf() / 1000,
            "iss":"urn:microsoft:windows-azure:zumo",
            "ver":1,
            "aud":aud,
            "uid":userId 
        };
        var s2 = JSON.stringify(j2);
        var b1 = urlFriendly(base64(s1));
        var b2 = urlFriendly(base64(s2));
        var b3 = signature(b1 + "." + b2);
        return [b1,b2,b3].join(".");
    }
```

I'm invoking like this:

```
        try 
        { 
            var loginInput = new JObject();
            loginInput.Add("userName", "breno");
            loginInput.Add("password", "test");
            var loginResult = await LoginAuthenticationService.InvokeApiAsync("login", loginInput);
            LoginAuthenticationService.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser((string)loginResult["user"]);
            LoginAuthenticationService.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = (string)loginResult["token"];
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
        {
            var exception = e;
        }
```

Comment: What do you see in the logs if you drop in a "console.log(results);" call before you check the length?  Are you certain that request.body.userName contains the username?

Comment: @Chris I update the post with how i invoke, im doing something wrong? Thanks for helping!!

Comment: It sounds like the request is making it to your custom API because you're getting the 500.  What do you see if you do a console.log(request.body) at the beginning of the post method?

Comment: @Chris I put console.log(request.body) like you said and get this on log: "Failed to load script file 'login.js': SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Comment: you're missing a `{` after `else` in `validateUserNamePassword` / `accounts.read` / `success`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting this error "Failed to load script file 'login.js': SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" as seen in the comments, there is a syntax issue with your script.  You'll need to go through your scripts and figure out where the issue is at.